# Replacing specific spaces with colons in a text file

Tags: linux, sed, removing-whitespace

I have a report that outputs to a text file in linux and I need it modified a bit.

**The file starts out like this if you cat it:**

```
  6 E8 B7 48 36 8C AE
  8 00 0C 85 F2 F9 07
  8 44 03 A7 C0 0D 26
  8 C8 4C 75 5C B1 55
 10 00 05 00 E7 5B 9F
 10 00 17 C5 69 49 A1
 10 00 1D A2 E7 BC F1
 12 00 16 9C 6C 53 C0
 14 00 0C 85 F2 F9 08
 26 00 05 00 E7 5B B7
```

Some random text will be down here also...

**I'm wanting it to look like this:**

```
  6 E8:B7:48:36:8C:AE
  8 00:0C:85:F2:F9:07
  8 44:03:A7:C0:0D:26
  8 C8:4C:75:5C:B1:55
 10 00:05:00:E7:5B:9F
 10 00:17:C5:69:49:A1
 10 00:1D:A2:E7:BC:F1
 12 00:16:9C:6C:53:C0
 14 00:0C:85:F2:F9:08
 26 00:05:00:E7:5B:B7
```

Some random text will be down here also...

**I was hoping to use sed to accomplish this.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way using sed:

```
sed 's/  */:/3g'  file
```

Comment: Not a good solution if there are space in front of the number like " 6" instead of "6".

Comment: @Jotne : Not sure what you meant. It does take care of those.

Comment: Try this two lines ` 6 E8 B7 48 36 8C AE` and `10 00 05 00 E7 5B 9F` Note there is a space in front of the `6`  First would become ` 6:E8:B7:48:36:8C:AE` and second `10 00:05:00:E7:5B:9F` Space after `6` is gone.

Comment: @Jotne: What you mentioned was not happening. updated the solution though to `3g` since the colons was coming a column before.

Comment: I was happening.  If you just copy data from Brian above, you would have 2 space in front of single digit and 1 space in front of double digit.  So now it works with the give data above.  But if space is removed, it would not work.  Jerrys `awk` and Bentoy13s `sed` works fine, with or without space in front.

Comment: This option appears to be working for me, thank you for the quick response!

Answer (score 3):

I think this would be easier with awk:

```
awk '{ printf("%2.2s %s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s\n", $1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7); }' file
```

Answer (score 3):

Following the answer of @Guru, you can try this one with `sed`:

```
sed -r 's/(\w) +/\1:/2g' file
```

You have to catch one letter before as `sed` does not support lookbehind.

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl, this will work with any number of alignment spaces:

```
perl -lane '($p,$m)=/^(\s*\d+\s*)(.*)$/; $m =~ s/ /:/g; print $p,$m' input
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed "
: doublept
   s/^\( *[[:digit:]]\{1,\}\)\( \{1,\}\)\(.*\) \([[:alnum:]]\{1,\}\)/\1\2\3:\4/
   t doublept
"
```

work also for bigger "mac address" if any (i think mainly same kind of problem for IP adress and IPv6)

Answer (score 0):

If you always know the line range for the numbers, you can use:-

```
sed 1,10s'/ /:/'g
```

The single quotes are important.